# Call JS function on each page load

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to call JS function on each page load in Blazor. The JS function initializes and html element so the `OnInitializedAsync` does not work for me, as the element is till not being rendered.

Everytime the page loads the OnAfterRenderAsync is being executed, but looks like that the JS function itself is not being executed correctly after the first render.

At the moment I do it in the 'OnAfterRenderAsync' method like so:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("jsFunctions.initEditor", "#editor");
}
```

But, this is executed on the first load (rendering) of the page. I need this JS function to be called on each render.

`#editor` is the id of textarea

```
<InputTextArea id="editor" @bind-Value="Model" />
```

---

`jsFunctions.initEditor` is the name of the JS function

```
window.jsFunctions = {
    initEditor: function (elementId) {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: elementId
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @daniherrera, I am currently doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Are you asking questions in riddle. So now we learn that the OnAfterRenderAsync method functions well, but the issue is with your JavaScript function, right ? So what about providing the code for the function and everything related, as for instance,  what is "#editor".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved the issue.

```
window.jsFunctions = {
    initEditor: function (elementId) {

        if (tinymce.editors.length > 0) {
            tinymce.remove(elementId);
        }

        tinymce.init({
            selector: elementId
        });
    }
}
```